# How to pick position coordinates of a Cesium 3d tile building feature?

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm having problems of extracting a center position coordinate values of an individual 3d tileset building in Cesium.

Is there any way of easily extracting the center position of a 3d tile feature in cesium?